# Nagios plugins/commands output to syslog

Tags: nagios, syslog

Do you know if is there any easy way to send output of every check run by nagios to syslog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small script which can be used as a notification and / or event handler. This was beneficial at the time since I did not want to log soft error states and the build I was working with could not separate the two. It also provides some formatting options.

This is easy to use by adding a user syslog with the notify-by-syslog options defined. Simply add this user as a contact whereever you want a specific service to log to syslog.

The Nagios command in the config file:

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-service-by-syslog
        command_line    /usr/bin/perl $USER1$/send_syslog.pl \
                 --state $SERVICESTATE$ --host $HOSTADDRESS$ \
                --msg "$HOSTADDRESS$ $SERVICEDESC$ $SERVICESTATE$ $SERVICEOUTPUT$ $LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$" --hard $SERVICESTATETYPE$
        }
define command{
        command_name    notify-host-by-syslog
        command_line    /usr/bin/perl $USER1$/send_syslog.pl \
                --hard $HOSTSTATETYPE$ --state $HOSTSTATE$ --host $HOSTADDRESS$ \
                --msg "$HOSTADDRESS$: $HOSTSTATE$ $HOSTOUTPUT$ $LONGHOSTOUTPUT$"
         }
```

The send_syslog.pl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Sys::Syslog qw(:standard :macros);
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
&Getopt::Long::config('bundling');

my $help;
my $hard;
my $state;
my $host;
my $msg;

get_options();
run_process();

sub run_process
{
    if( $hard eq "SOFT" )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    my $alert=LOG_DEBUG;
    $alert=LOG_EMERG    if $state eq  "DOWN";
    $alert=LOG_INFO     if $state eq  "UP";
    $alert=LOG_CRIT     if $state eq  "CRITICAL";
    $alert=LOG_WARNING  if $state eq  "WARNING";
    $alert=LOG_INFO     if $state eq  "OK";

    openlog('nagios','','daemon');
    syslog($alert,"$host     $msg");
}

sub get_options
{
    GetOptions
        ("help|h"        => \$help,
         "hard:s"        => \$hard,
         "state:s"       => \$state,
         "host:s"        => \$host,
         "msg:s"         => \$msg
         );
    if( defined($help) )
    {
        print "--help called\n\n";
        print_usage();
    }
}
sub print_usage
{
    print "--help | -H: Print this screen\n";
    print "--hard <HOSTSTATETYPE|SERVICESTATETYPE>\n";
    print "  with a SOFT or HARD state; only alerts on the HARD states.\n";
    print "--state <HOSTSTATE|SERVICESTATE>";
    print "--host <HOSTADDRESS>\n";
    print "--msg <Message Body>: Defines the message body to render\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this was what I finally did too, although my scripts is in bash to reduce overhead (we have LOTS of services monitored).

Answer (score 2):

Did you set up the `use_syslog` option in Nagios configuration?

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#use_syslog